# Base class or Abstract class without abstract method

Tags: oop, interface, abstract-class

I have a problem to chose the between an abstract class without abstract methods OR a base class with an interface.

I have two implementation in my mind:

### 1.

Let's say I have a `AbstractRenderer`:

```
abstract class AbstractRenderer
{

    protected $shape;

    public function __construct(AbstractShape $shape)
    {
        $this->shape = $shape;
    }

    public function render(): string
    {
        return $this->shape->generate()->asArray();
    }
}
```

and the WebRenderer would be like this:

```
class WebRenderer extends AbstractRenderer
{

}
```

### 2.

Have a base class and an interface like this:

```
Interface InterfaceRenderer
{
   public function __construct(AbstractShape $shape);
   public function render(): string;
}
```

and a base class that impediments the interface:

```
class BaseRenderer implements InterfaceRenderer
{
        protected $shape;

        public function __construct(AbstractShape $shape)
        {
            $this->shape = $shape;
        }

        public function render(): string
        {
            return $this->shape->generate()->toString();
        }
}
```

again, my WebRenderer would be like this:

```
class WebRenderer extends BaseRenderer
{

}
```

I don't know which is the correct implementation, or there is a better way to implement this and what is the pros and cons of each.

Thanks

Comment: btw, I searched and read other questions, google and other resources. but couldn't find any useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the Renderer client’s perspective the 2 solutions are basically identical. As long as they depend on an abstract object (interface or an abstract class), you’ll have benefits of polymorphism. You’d lose those if you make them depend on WebRenderer (concrete object).

**Interface’s benefits over abstract classes**

- doesn’t occupy inheritance
- no fragile base class problem

**Abstract classes provide**

- static methods (in many languages interface can’t have these)
- protected implementation